# How to integrate external dependencies in a web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, web-applications

I am writing my first web application using npm, nodejs and react components. This is all rather new stuff for me.

I need to deploy this web application on an server in a LAN. Both the server and the clients have no access to the internet. I followed some tutorials to instantiate my first implementation of the web app. The problem is that now the web application references libraries and css via CDN links (e.g. specified in index.html).

My question is if there is a standard and automatic way to build the web application so that the building process would automatically download all the external dependencies and convert all the references from the outside world to the local paths.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check that and let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if there is a standard and automatic way to build the web application so that the building process would automatically download all the external dependencies and convert all the references from the outside world to the local paths.

You need to use module bundler like webpack.

Then the basic app would look similar to this:

Project structure:

```
..
src
    ..
    js
        ..
        <your react files here>
    css
        ..
        <your css files here>
    index.htm
    index.js
package.json
.babelrc
webpack.config.js
```

index.js

```
import 'some/library/from/node_modules';
import YourApp from "./js/YourApp.jsx";
```

So then you could be able to bundle your React app with css files, fonts, js libraries etc into a single file with no external dependencies and serve it by Node.js like a static file.

Here is a good article about this: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/

Comment: I read the tutorial. Everything worked as expected, except one important thing: my index.html template comes from the react-web-app npm. Inside this file there are meta strings like href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" or ven more standard href point to cdn resources, which are processed by react-scripts. How can I make webpack to process the template index.html in this form?

Comment: @Martin change the favicon path to relative like `somewhere/favicon.ico`, then you can serve it by your Node.js server.

About cdn resources: first of all, try to find libraries, that are downloaded from cdn, in npm. There are good chances, that they are there. Then you can just `npm i ` them and import in your `index.js`. And if they are not, you always can manually download the libraries you need and give them to your app from your Node.js server.

Comment: I tried to download the bootstrap css file and put it in src. In index.js I import it, but now the builing process complains about fonts not being correctly referenced. Do you know how to solve this problem cleatly? ./src/bootstrap.min.css
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Comment: @Martin did you just downloaded it or installed as node module via npm?

As I wrote before, you should search for the libraries you need in npm first.  

According to the official bootstrap instructions for webpack, that can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/
You should first install bootstrap with `npm i bootstrap` and the include it to your react app with `import 'bootstrap';` and `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` - for bootstrap css. Also please check, that you added css-loader to webpack config as described in article.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nodejs` to do that.

Here is an example that you can use with `gulp` to copy all dependencies to a `vendor` folder using `gulp-npm-dist`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-npm-dist

This package will automatically download and copy your `vendors` based on your `package.json`. This is the easiest way to do it and you can easily update and manage all your packages versions with this method.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Karim